# java sql exception on DB2, Cursor state not valid

Tags: java, db2, state

Here is my source code.
This source code has no problem.
but sometimes, I met a problem with 'Cursor state not valid' like below exception message.
20211214082151/SQL SELECT/com.dao.TransactionDetailDAO/getDataList()/**Cursor state not valid.**

This problem has been left unresolved for too long.
Please someone help me. Why this problem happening? and How to solve this problem.
***The Point is 'sometimes'. This exception happened around once in fifty.***

```
public Vector getDataList(int arg1, int arg2, long arg3, int arg4) {

    Vector vList = new Vector();

    try {
        m_conn = CSDBConnection.getConnection();
        String sQuery = "select DATA1,DATA2 from " + TABLE + " where ARG1= ? and ARG2=? and ARG3=? and ARG4 =? ";

        m_pstmt = m_conn.prepareStatement(sQuery);
        int i = 0;
        m_pstmt.setInt(++i, arg1);
        m_pstmt.setInt(++i, arg2);
        m_pstmt.setLong(++i, arg3);
        m_pstmt.setInt(++i, arg4);

        m_rs = m_pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (m_rs.next()) {
            String[] aResult = new String[2];
            aResult[0] = Integer.toString(m_rs.getInt("DATA1"));
            aResult[1] = m_rs.getString("DATA2");
            vList.add(aResult);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ErrorLog.writeLog(ErrorLog.ERR_DELETE_SQL, "TransactionDetailDAO", "getDataList", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        CSDBConnection.cleanup(m_rs, m_pstmt);
    }
    return vList;
}
```

detail exception logs

```
TimeStamp:  / 2021-12-16 05:01:00
Error Message : Internal driver error. (class java.lang.NullPointerException)   Error Cause : java.lang.NullPointerException
Error toString : java.sql.SQLException: Internal driver error. (class java.lang.NullPointerException)
StackTraceElement Index : 0 FileName : JDError.java LineNumber : 985    ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.JDError    MethodName : createSQLExceptionSubClass
StackTraceElement Index : 1 FileName : JDError.java LineNumber : 610    ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.JDError    MethodName : throwSQLException
StackTraceElement Index : 2 FileName : JDError.java LineNumber : 568    ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.JDError    MethodName : throwSQLException
StackTraceElement Index : 3 FileName : AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.java LineNumber : 3163   ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl    MethodName : sendAndReceive
StackTraceElement Index : 4 FileName : AS400JDBCStatement.java  LineNumber : 1805   ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement MethodName : commonPrepare
StackTraceElement Index : 5 FileName : AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl.java  LineNumber : 357    ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl MethodName : <init>
StackTraceElement Index : 6 FileName : AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.java LineNumber : 2313   ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl    MethodName : prepareStatement
StackTraceElement Index : 7 FileName : AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.java LineNumber : 2084   ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl    MethodName : prepareStatement
StackTraceElement Index : 8 FileName : AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.java LineNumber : 2079   ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl    MethodName : prepareStatement
StackTraceElement Index : 9 FileName : Atk_MiscDao.java LineNumber : 37 ClassName : com.connector.dao.mes.Atk_MiscDao   MethodName : getMiscInfo2ByTable
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeStamp:  / 2021-12-16 07:04:56
Error Message : Communication link failure. (Disconnect request received, connection terminated.)   Error Cause : com.ibm.as400.access.ConnectionDroppedException: Disconnect request received, connection terminated.
Error toString : java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communication link failure. (Disconnect request received, connection terminated.)
StackTraceElement Index : 0 FileName : JDError.java LineNumber : 884    ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.JDError    MethodName : createSQLExceptionSubClass
StackTraceElement Index : 1 FileName : JDError.java LineNumber : 610    ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.JDError    MethodName : throwSQLException
StackTraceElement Index : 2 FileName : JDError.java LineNumber : 568    ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.JDError    MethodName : throwSQLException
StackTraceElement Index : 3 FileName : AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.java LineNumber : 3147   ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl    MethodName : sendAndReceive
StackTraceElement Index : 4 FileName : AS400JDBCStatement.java  LineNumber : 1805   ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement MethodName : commonPrepare
StackTraceElement Index : 5 FileName : AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl.java  LineNumber : 357    ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl MethodName : <init>
StackTraceElement Index : 6 FileName : AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.java LineNumber : 2313   ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl    MethodName : prepareStatement
StackTraceElement Index : 7 FileName : AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.java LineNumber : 2084   ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl    MethodName : prepareStatement
StackTraceElement Index : 8 FileName : AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.java LineNumber : 2079   ClassName : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl    MethodName : prepareStatement
StackTraceElement Index : 9 FileName : Atk_MiscDao.java LineNumber : 37 ClassName : com.connector.dao.mes.Atk_MiscDao   MethodName : getMiscInfo2ByTable
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You need to close `m_conn` in the `finally` block.

Comment: Thanks for reply. the connection already closed by another source. this problem is not related about closing connection.

Comment: @HMLEE Your question lacks detail. Please edit your question to add the full exception text including the stacktrace. Please specif the exact jdbc driver you are using (from which supplier, and which version is the driver).  Also please specify the Db2-server platform (z/os,  i-series/as400,  linux/unix/windows/cloud).  The symptom you see can have different causes but only the exact details can lead to the correct cause.

Comment: Thank you. but unfortunately, this is all of exception message (from e.getMessage()) <Cursor state not valid.>
and i'm using jt400.jar (old version. i'm not sure exactly version info)
finally this service has going on windows server 2012.
as your comment it seems caused very specific case. for example heavy traffic.

Comment: @HMLEE jt400.jar is for use only with i-series (as/400) and not Windows-Server-2012. Add `e.printStackTrace();` or equivalent to the exception handler to get stack trace. This needs to be in your question as plain text. Otherwise your question will be closed for lack of detail. Use current jdbc driver versions when testing.

Comment: @mao
Hi, mao. Thanks again for your reply. I was check jt400 version and adding detail logs.
the version is jtopen 10.7 and then my application is going on windows server 2012.
but, as you mentioned. surely the DB is on i-series in my factory.
Anyway, please refer the attached detail logs. also it was happened today again.
i'm not sure what happened between DB2 and my application. (there are few different errors...)

Comment: The null pointer exception appears unconnected with your previous symptom. I suggest you pay a pro to debug and fix the app / configuration on a development environment to resolve the problems.